# How can I summarize the total amount of a certain column which is only after the keywords?

Tags: bash

I have data with variable columns shown below

```
...
FRAM_#     19998800      4999700(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.056      8128     CA  2.426      7589     AL  1.920
FRAM_#     19998900      4999725(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.039      8128     CA  2.311      7589     AL  1.962
FRAM_#     19999000      4999750(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.052      8128     CA  2.400      7589     AL  1.912
FRAM_#     19999100      3230225(fs)  CN= 2 PRMRYTGT    13046   Pa*    14277      H  1.064      8128     CA  2.477      7589     AL  1.930      7358     AL  2.330
FRAM_#     19999200      4523675(fs)  CN= 2 PRMRYTGT    13046   Pa*    14277      H  1.051      8128     CA  2.546      7589     AL  1.950      7358     AL  2.336
FRAM_#     19999300      4999825(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  0.973      8128     CA  2.385      7589     AL  2.034
FRAM_#     19999400      4999850(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.033      8128     CA  2.437      7589     AL  1.932
FRAM_#     19999500      4999875(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.015      8128     CA  2.367      7589     AL  1.979
FRAM_#     19999600      4999900(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.003      8128     CA  2.363      7589     AL  1.963
FRAM_#     19999700      4999925(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.068      8128     CA  2.467      7589     AL  1.925
FRAM_#     19999800      4999950(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.004      8128     CA  2.435      7589     AL  1.941
FRAM_#     19999900      4999975(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  1.062      8128     CA  2.303      7589     AL  1.911
FRAM_#     20000000      5000000(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT    13046   Ac*    14277      H  0.991      8128     CA  2.359      7589     AL  2.002
...
```

I want to summarize the value after keyword "AL". How can I summarize these values if the column number is different?

I can only calculate column number is 17 or 20 separately (in above example, may more or less columns in my whole data) using code below

```
grep FRAME filename |grep "AL" | awk '{if(NF == 20){print $0}}' |awk '{s+= $20} END {print s}'
```

You may notice the line #4 and #5 have two "AL". I want to summarize the value after them. If I use above command, only the last one can be summarized, if I change the value 20 to 17, the values for the first "AL" would be missed. Worse, my data is more than thousands, it is infeasible to check it manually. I hope to improve my script to make it more robotic for data with variable column numbers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
grep FRAM_ filename | awk '{if ($17 == "AL") s+=$18; if(NF == 20) if ($19 == "AL") s+=$20 } END {print s}'
```

awk looks at every line and if record 17 is equals to AL then summarize record 18, after this, checks if line has 20 records and in this case, if record 19 is equals to AL then summarize record 20.

At the end s should give you total sum of AL record in 18 and 20 position if is present.

If it is unknown where is "AL" token, try this:

```
grep FRAM_ filename | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "AL") s+=$(i+1); } END {print s}'
```

If file is big, you can avoid grep and call awk:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "AL") s+=$(i+1); } END {print s}' filename
```